# Run a function in background using thread in Flask

Tags: python, json, flask, python-multithreading

I am trying to implement limit order book using flask and I am working on the backend part right now. I am new to flask so I am still learning and I am not much aware about how backend of trading works but I am trying to learn via this small project.

I have created 3 endpoints in my application which add order, remove order and give a response of the order status and these three endpoints are working fine checked them with postman. Now I am trying to run a function  in background which will continuously check the new orders (buy/sell) from a json file which save all new orders. It will pick them one by one and will find a match based on price if a user's buy order matches a different user's sell order it will process and store it in a dict which I want to return or store all those successful order to the user.
Here is my code for the class I have created:

```
import json
import bisect
import random
import os

class Process(object):

  def __init__(self):

    self.trade_book = []
    self.bid_prices = []
    self.ask_prices = []
    self.ask_book = {}
    self.bid_book = {}
    self.confirm_traded = []
    self.orders_history = {}
    self.traded = False
    self.counter = 0
    

def save_userdata(self,order, newId):
    
    orderid = order['order']['trader'] +"_"+ str(newId)

    user_list = order
    newJson = {
        "orders":[
            { orderid: order['order']}
        ]
    }
    with open('data_user.json', 'a+') as jsonFile:
        with open('data_user.json', 'r') as readableJson:
            try:
                 jsonObj = json.load(readableJson)
            except Exception as e:
                jsonObj = {}
        if jsonObj == {}:
            json.dump(newJson, jsonFile)
        else:
            with open('data_user.json', 'w+') as writeFile:
                exists = False
                for item in jsonObj['orders']:
                    if item.get(orderid, None) is not None:
                        item[orderid] = order['order']
                        exists = True
                        break
                if not exists:
                    jsonObj['orders'].append(newJson['orders'][0])
                json.dump(jsonObj, writeFile)
        
        return orderid


  def get_userdata(self):
    with open('data_user.json', 'r') as readableJson:
        return json.load(readableJson)


  def removeOrder(self, orderid):

    order_id = list(orderid.values())[0]
    with open('data_user.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
    newData = []
    for item in data['orders']:
        if item.get(order_id, None) is not None:
            del item[order_id]
        else:
            newData.append(item)
    data['orders'] = newData
    with open('data_user.json', 'w') as data_file:
        data = json.dump(data, data_file)

    return order_id



 def add_order_to_book(self, order):

    index = list(order.keys())[0]
    book_order = order[index]
    print(index)

    if order[index]['side'] == 'buy':
        book_prices = self.bid_prices
        book = self.bid_book
    
    else: #order[index]['side'] == 'sell'
        book_prices = self.ask_prices
        book = self.ask_book
    
    if order[index]['price'] in book_prices:
        book[order[index]['price']]['num_orders'] += 1
        book[order[index]['price']]['size'] += order[index]['quantity']
        book[order[index]['price']]['order_ids'].append(index)
        book[order[index]['price']]['orders'][index] = book_order
        

    else:
        bisect.insort(book_prices, order[index]['price'])
        book[order[index]['price']] = {'num_orders': 1, 'size': order[index]['quantity'],'order_ids': 
     [index],
                               'orders': {index: book_order}}



def confirm_trade(self,order_id, timestamp, order_quantity, order_price, order_side):
     
    
    trader = order_id.partition('_')[0]
    self.confirm_traded.append({ 'trader': trader,'quantity': order_quantity, 'side': order_side, 
 'price': order_price,
                                'status': 'Successful'})
    
    
    return self.confirm_traded


def process_trade_orders(self, order):
    
    self.traded = False
    index = list(order.keys())[0]
    if order[index]['side'] == 'buy':
        book = self.ask_book
        if order[index]['price'] in self.ask_prices:
            remainder = order[index]['quantity']
            while remainder > 0:
                book_order_id = book[order[index]['price']]['order_ids'][0]
                book_order = book[order[index]['price']]['orders'][book_order_id]

                if remainder >= book_order['quantity']:
                    self.trade_book.append({'order_id': book_order_id, 'timestamp': order[index]['timestamp'], 
                        'price': order[index]['price'],
                        'quantity': order[index]['quantity'], 'side': book_order['side']})
                    self.confirm_trade(index, order[index]['timestamp'], order[index]['quantity'], order[index]['price'], order[index]['side'])
                    self.traded = True

                    remainder = remainder - book_order['quantity']
                    self.save_historty_orders(index, order[index])
                    break
                            

                else:
                    self.traded = True
                    self.trade_book.append({'order_id': index, 'timestamp': order[index]['timestamp'], 
                        'price': order[index]['price'],
                        'quantity': order[index]['quantity'], 'side': order[index]['side']})
                    self.confirm_trade(index, order[index]['timestamp'], order[index]['quantity'], order[index]['price'], order[index]['side'])
                    self.save_historty_orders(index, order[index])
                    break

        else:
            self.add_order_to_book(order)
            self.save_historty_orders(index, order[index])


    
    else: #order['side'] == 'sell'
        book = self.bid_book
        if order[index]['price'] in self.bid_prices:
            remainder = order[index]['quantity']
            while remainder > 0:
                book_order_id = book[order[index]['price']]['order_ids'][0]
                book_order = book[order[index]['price']]['orders'][book_order_id]

                if remainder >= book_order['quantity']:

                    self.trade_book.append({'order_id': book_order_id, 'timestamp': order[index]['timestamp'], 
                        'price': order[index]['price'],
                        'quantity': order[index]['quantity'], 'side': order[index]['side']})
                    self.traded = True
                    self.confirm_trade(index, order[index]['timestamp'], order[index]['quantity'], order[index]['price'], order[index]['side'])

                    remainder = remainder - book_order['quantity']
                    self.save_historty_orders(index, order[index])
                    break


                else:
                    self.traded = True
                    self.trade_book.append({'order_id': book_order_id, 'timestamp': order[index]['timestamp'], 
                        'price': order[index]['price'],
                        'quantity': order[index]['quantity'], 'side': order[index]['side']})
                    self.confirm_trade(index, order[index]['timestamp'], order[index]['quantity'], order[index]['price'], order[index]['side'])
                    self.save_historty_orders(index, order[index])
                    break

        else:
            self.add_order_to_book(order)
            self.save_historty_orders(index, order[index])
```

This class process I create object in my app.py and call the function process_trade_orders in that inside a function processing():

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True

    newUser = Process()
    succorder = Success()
    #sched = BackgroundScheduler()

    def generate_orderid():
        num = 0
        while num < 1000:
            yield num
            num = num + 1

    genid = generate_orderid()
  
   proc = Process()
   sucorder = Success()

   #Processing orders to find if they have a match
   def processing():

       get_orders_data = proc.get_userdata()
       print(get_orders_data)
       print("\n")

       for data in get_orders_data['orders']:

           index = list(data.keys())[0]
           if data[index]['status'] == 'Successful':
               sucorder.add_trader_orders(data[index],index)
           else:
               proc.process_trade_orders(data)


   # sched = BackgroundScheduler()
   # sched.add_job(func = processing, trigger="interval", seconds = 2)
   # sched.start()
```

I did use APSbackground-scheduler for the same but I want to use thread for it. I was thinking of running a main thread in infinite loop as a daemon and use worker thread to run this function processing() in app.py which will be called after every few seconds to check if there are any successful order it will return the value to the main thread and those list of dict every new one I can return a response or some other way to the user about this successful order getting matched.

Note that this will be running is short intervals like 5 seconds and multiple add orders will be added and will be continuously running the checks asynchronously so I am not sure how will I return those values. I am just confused so if anyone can help me will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a threaded function that runs in background, just use the `threading` module, like this:

```
from threading import Thread
def bg_func():
    doSomething
t = Thread(target=bg_func)
t.start() # will start the function and continue, even if the function still runs
doSomethingelseAtSameTime # runs with bg_func
```

You can also have multiple background threads.

Check the documentation for more info.

Comment: I have tried this before but i want to share my data with the main thread so that i can give some response or return value to the user. As this function will be running continuously after every 5 secs my concern is data will be frequently updated then how can I use it. I mentioned above a way i was thinking like using main thread and running worker thread. Please can you check my question once. Thanks!!

Comment: I am new to implementing limit order book and beginner in flask too so i am a bit confused.

Comment: The function also works if you use a class or a (bad) global variable. Nothing is separed, you're just doing multiple things at once.